# SQL syntax error using joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Hoping I can get some help with my SQL syntax. I haven't been able to fix the problem on my own. I used a syntax checker which it says my code is good but I'm getting an error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.PO_KEY,
    DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.SO_KEY,
    DATALIVE.CO_PICK_LOTS_DETAIL.SO_KEY,
    Sum(DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.QTY_ALLOC) AS SumOfQTY_ALLOC,
    Sum(DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.PO_ALLOC_QTY) AS SumOfPO_ALLOC_QTY, 
    Sum(DATALIVE.CO_PICK_LOTS_DETAIL.QTY) AS Picked_Qty,
    Min(DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.ALLOC_DATE) AS MinOfALLOC_DATE, 
    Max(DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.ALLOC_DATE) AS MaxOfALLOC_DATE,
    DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.STATUS
FROM (DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL
INNER JOIN DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.SO_KEY
    ON DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.SO_KEY = DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.SO_KEY)
INNER JOIN DATALIVE.CO_PICK_LOTS_DETAIL
    ON DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.SO_KEY = DATALIVE.CO_PICK_LOTS_DETAIL.SO_KEY 
GROUP BY DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.PO_KEY,
    DATALIVE.CO_ALLOCATION_TAIL.SO_KEY,
    DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.STATUS,
    DATALIVE.CO_PICK_LOTS_DETAIL.SO_KEY
HAVING (((DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.STATUS) = 'O'))
```

Comment: Please edit your code and format it in a readable form.

Comment: Also, please post the error you're getting.

Comment: The error code I'm getting is: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN DATALIVE.CO_SORDER.SO_KEY
```

That's a column, not a table. Needs a table, like `DATALIVE.CO_SORDER`.